# Remove duplicate lines from multiple text files

Tags: php, unix

I have 100 .txt files with ~ 1 mln lines each.

Is there a way to open all the files, remove duplicates and save the lines accordingly to each file (php/unix etc)?

---

**For example:**

file1.txt contents

```
Something here1
Something here2
```

file2.txt contents

```
Something here2
Something here3
```

---

**After removal:**

file1.txt contents

```
Something here1
Something here2
```

file2.txt contents

```
Something here 3
```

Comment: I had two different answers at first, then I looked a little closer at your question. It's more difficult than I thought. For other would-be answerers, notice that the OP wants to remove lines from one file if they exist in any other file. This is different then just removing all duplicate lines within each file.

Comment: Does the order of the lines matter within each file when you're done? If not, the `sort -u` command may be useful, but it doesn't directly do what you're looking for. It may be a starting point though, for someone smarter than myself.

Comment: Yes, I already sort -u them, now I need to remove the duplicates from the other files also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this, it works. Order of lines is not maintained within each file, but you said in a comment that you're already applying `sort`, so that doesn't matter. It's a little roundabout, but it does work:

```
   #!/bin/bash

   #The number of files you have, named like file1.txt, file2.txt, etc.
   # If named otherwise, cahnge the definition of variable "file" in the loop below.
   NUM_FILES=3

   #These files will be created and removed during the script, so make sure they're
   # not files you already have around.
   tempfile1="_all.txt"
   tempfile2="_tmp.txt"

   sort -u file1.txt > file1out.txt
   cat file1out.txt > $tempfile1

   for i in $(seq 2 $NUM_FILES)
   do
       prev=$((i-1))
       pofile="file${prev}out.txt"
       file="file$i.txt"
       ofile="file${i}out.txt"

       echo "Input files: $file $pofile"
       echo "Output file: $ofile"
       cat $tempfile1 $pofile > $tempfile2
       sort -u $tempfile2 > $tempfile1
       sort -u $file | comm -23 - $tempfile1 > $ofile
   done

   rm -f $tempfile1 $tempfile2
```

Comment: Great, glad I finally figured it out, it took a couple of tries. Hope the script makes sense to you as well.

Answer (score 1):

Using Unix sort & grep:

**If order of lines doesn't matter:**

```
 sort -u file1.txt > _temp && mv _temp file1.txt
```

**If order of lines matters:**

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} ($0 in a) {delete a[$0]; print}' file1.txt file1.txt _temp && mv _temp file1.txt
 grep -v -f file1.txt file2.txt > _temp && mv _temp file2.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

- get the each line of the file as array

> ```
> $file1 = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file1.txt')); 
> $file2 = explode("\n", file_get_contents('file2.txt'));
> ```

- use array_unique to remove the duplicates with in the file

> ```
> $f1 = array_unique($file1); 
> $f2 = array_unique($file2);
> ```

- Remove duplicates from second array compare with first

> ```
> $new_f2 = array_diff($f2,$f1);
> ```

Now you have $f1 and $new_f2 unique values.

Now just update the files.

> Note: for multiple files do this recursively